# msRequestFullscreen not working in case keydown event (IE 11)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keydown, html5-fullscreen

I`m working with fullscreen api.

I`ve added this polyfill:

```
let doc = document as any;
if (!doc.requestFullscreen) {
  document.body.requestFullscreen = doc.body.mozRequestFullScreen || 
    doc.body.webkitRequestFullscreen || doc.body.msRequestFullscreen;
  document.exitFullscreen = doc.mozCancelFullScreen || doc.webkitExitFullscreen || 
    doc.msExitFullscreen;
}
```

I have UI button for enabling fullscreen mode and all works fine (chrome IE 11, edge, opera, firefox)

Also I have keydown handler:

```
if (args.keyCode === 70) {
  args.preventDefault();
  if (!this.isInFullScreen) {
    document.body.requestFullscreen();
  } 
  else {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }
  this.InFullScreen = !this.isInFullScreen;
}
```

But enabling/disabling fullcreen mode by pressing F **doesn`t work in IE 11.**
msRequestFullscreen function simply do nothing.
There are no console errors or smth.
In other browsers works fine.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue. `msRequestFullscreen` works in IE 11 but it just doesn't work in `keyCode` event.

As a workaround, I suggest that you can use `ActiveXObject` to `SendKeys` F11. It can make it full screen in IE 11. You can add the following code:

```
if ("ActiveXObject" in window) {
   var wscript = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
   wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This workaround adds some non-user-friendly behavior.
Need to add site to trusted and change some settings.
And you can`t exit fullscreen via UI click or F pressing again, only F11 works.

Comment: Yes, it needs to change some IE settings. I also find [a similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c9bd47e1-c81d-4973-87d0-96a720a5b894/fullscreen-api?forum=iewebdevelopment) and it looks like there's no other solutions now. As IE is going to retire, I'm not sure if this issue will be fixed. Let's wait to see if other community members have any other workarounds.